# Tkinter, Flashing Window after calling "wm_iconbitmap" and "resizable"

Tags: python, tkinter

Everytime I create a window set and icon for the window manager and change some other property of the window (e.c. "resizable") it "flash" up. I suppose this is because the window manager is called again and it redos the window. Is there any way I can call maybe a "silent" change or something like that? I have not been very lucky in my research.

If you want to see for yourself, you are going to need an icon file. I uploaded the icon I am using [here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8316798/icon.ico.html). If you are not comfortable with downloading that, you can also find suitable icon files in your system directory. Search "*.ico". Any 16x16 icon will do.

```
#! coding=utf-8
import tkinter as tk
import os

def CENTER_WINDOW(window,parent):
    """ Verschiebt ein Fenster auf dem Bildschirm"""        
    # get window size
    window.update_idletasks()
    w = window.winfo_width()
    h = window.winfo_height()

    # get parent size
    if parent=="screen":
        p_x , p_y  = window.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()
        p_ox, p_oy = 0,0
    else:
        parent.update_idletasks()
        p_x , p_y  = parent.geometry().split("+")[0].split("x")
        p_x , p_y  = int(p_x) , int(p_y)
        p_ox, p_oy = int(parent.geometry().split("+")[1]),int(parent.geometry().split("+")[2])

    # calculate position x, y
    x = p_x/2 + p_ox - w/2
    y = p_y/2 + p_oy - h/2

    window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x,y))
    window.update_idletasks()

def top():
    T = tk.Toplevel()
    T.wm_iconbitmap( os.path.abspath("icon.ico"))
    T.resizable(width=tk.FALSE, height=tk.FALSE)
    CENTER_WINDOW(T,root)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x50")
but = tk.Button(root,text="Toplevel",command=top)
CENTER_WINDOW(root,"screen")
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In rough outline:

- Call withdraw on the window immediately after creating it
- Make your adjustments
- Call deiconify on the window when you're ready to show it