# Tkinter's root window recreates automatically after calling root.resizable()

Tags: python, tkinter, window, resizable, visual-glitch

Root window 'rebuilds' after calling `root.resizable`. This cause visual glitch, in which window looks like it was minimized and instantly normalized in around 100 msec.

I tried to use withdraw + deiconify (like here: [Tkinter, Flashing Window after calling "wm_iconbitmap" and "resizable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122955/tkinter-flashing-window-after-calling-wm-iconbitmap-and-resizable)), but it didn't help.

There is a minimalistic example and it's glitch recording: https://youtu.be/4tFhI0TOyNE

```
import tkinter as tk


def hide_1():
    #root.withdraw()
    root.resizable(True, True)  # enabling this line causes window 'blink'
    frame1.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack(expand=True) 
    #root.deiconify()


def hide_2():
    #root.withdraw()
    root.resizable(False, False)    # enabling this line causes window 'blink'
    frame2.pack_forget()
    frame1.pack(expand=True)
    #root.deiconify()


root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=200, height=200)

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
btn1 = tk.Button(frame1, text='hide frame1, show frame2', command=lambda: hide_1())
btn1.pack()
frame1.pack(expand=True)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
btn2 = tk.Button(frame2, text='hide frame2, show frame1',  command=lambda: hide_2())
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**UPD:** There is the most minimalistic example. No `pack_forget()` or `withdraw()` or `deiconify()` calling. Just raw `root.resizable()` call.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=200, height=200)

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Resize_Off', command=lambda: root.resizable(False, False))
btn1.pack()

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='Resize_On',  command=lambda: root.resizable(True, True))
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not a glitch and if anything, having `withdraw` and `deiconify` would cause that.
Alright, so if that's caused by `root.resizable` not much you can do there probably.

Comment: "window looks like it was minimized and instantly normalized" - because that's precisely what's happening. Did you perhaps mean to call `iconify()` to keep the root window minimized?

Comment: @JRiggles no. I wanted to enable/disable window resizing by pressing button. but this causes window glitch, which looks like window was minimized and normalized instantly (also looks like window was recreated from scratch) Also, watch video pls, for better understanding

Comment: @Matiiss well, this doesn't sound promising

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter is behaving as designed. You're explicitly withdrawing the window and then causing it to be redisplayed. If you don't want the visual artifact, remove the calls to `root.withdraw()`

This appears to be a quirk on whatever platform you're running on. I don't see any flicker when I run your code on my Mac.

Comment: watch video pls. This happens even without withdraw... root.resizable() cause this

Comment: @MIku: it doesn't for me. The contents inside the window flicker briefly, but that's to be expected since the inside is changing.

Comment: i'm not talking about widgets (window's content) flickering, but about the whole window 'falling' or 'hiding and appearing instantly' or 'window boarder blinking'. If you watch the video, you will understand the difference, as long as i showed there that window's content doesn't blink with disabling `root.resizable()` line

Comment: @miku: _"i'm not talking about widgets (window's content) flickering"_ - yes, I know. And I'm saying that the window itself doesn't flicker for me when I take out the calls to `root.withdraw()`.  If you're seeing it only when you call `root.resizable`, I recommend removing the call to `root.resizable`. Non-resizable windows are the opposite of user-friendly design.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I think, this is the best advice for that case :)